# Toggle element with loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is when a user clicks a button, to change the image of the button to a loading icon.

My javascript function looks like this -

```
function GenerateDetail() {
    var resBtn = $('ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot').find("btn_generateDetail");
    if (resBtn != null) {
        toggleElement(resBtn);
    }
}

function toggleElement(aRelEle) {
    if ($(aRelEle).css("display") != "none") {
        addImage(aRelEle);
        $(aRelEle).css("display", "none");
    }
    else {
        $(aRelEle).prev().remove();
        $(aRelEle).css("display", "inline");
    }
}

function addImage(aParEle) {
    var aImage = document.createElement("img");
    var aSrc = "App_Themes/Images/activityloader.gif";
    aImage.border = "0";
    aImage.src = aSrc;
    aParEle.appendChild(aImage);
}
```

In toggleElement, $(aRelEle).css("display") is undefined. Why? 'ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot' is a div I have around all of my elements on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies with this line:

```
 var resBtn = $('ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot').find("btn_generateDetail");
```

What is ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot? is it a class? Then it should be .ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot or is it an id? Then it should be: #ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot

Similarly for your find(). Is btn_generateDetail an id or a class?

Comment: 'ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot' is a div I have around all of my elements on my page. I am trying to find that button within that div.

Comment: so is it a class to the div or an id? i.e. is it like( <div class='ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot'>...</div> or <div id='ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot'>...</div>

Comment: <div id='cntnrRoot' runat='server'>

Comment: Awesome, so try: var resBtn = $('div#ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot').find("#btn_generateDetail"); that is assuming btn_generateDetail is an id as well

Comment: Thanks, that definitely finds the button. However, when I enter my toggleElement function, on this line - if ($(aRelEle).css("display") != "none"), $(aRelEle).css("display") evaluates to undefined. Why?

Comment: This may be a short in the dark but try replacing  if ($(aRelEle).css("display") != "none") with  if (aRelEle.css("display") != "none")

Comment: My reasoning for the above is because with  $('div#ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot').find("#btn_generateDetail"); you are effectively selecting the element you need to change and that is returned a a jquery object already so you do not need to put it inside a jquery selector again. I found this through the jquery find docs: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: This line - $('div#ctl00_cpMain_cntnrRoot').find("#btn_generateDetail"); doesn't seem to actually find the button within that div. The button actually exists within a table within that div. Do I need to be more specific with my find command to find within that table?

Comment: can you paste the entire btn_generateDetail tag? Or possible some of your html code. It would be much easier to find the problem if we get an idea of what the DOM looks like.

Comment: from my aspx page - <asp:Button ID="btn_generateDetail" style="display:block;" runat="server" Text="Generate Detail"/>.. from page/view source - <input type="submit" name="ctl00$cpMain$btn_generateDetail" value="Generate Detail" onclick="GenerateDetail();" id="ctl00_cpMain_btn_generateDetail" style="display:block;" />

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a html button tag. If so you could put the image in the button and give it a style of display="none" then you could just toggle this style when button clicked.
example:

```
<button>
    <img id="loadingIcon" src="" style="display:none"/> Button Text Here
</button>
```

Comment: How would I find that img through javascript to toggle it back and forth?

Comment: I would reference it by it's id. So you could do something like: document.getElementById("loadingIcon").style.display = "inline"; or document.getElementByID("loadingIcon").style.display = "none"; I think this may be easier than creating a function.